# google cloud platform no permission to download from SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform

when I try to download a file while in the ssh for a vm instance in the root\ directory, it says failed. Trying to access the file, it said no permission

Comment: Would you post all the commands that you run ? This might be an expected behavior if you ran the ssh command as normal user as the root directory is owned by the root user. However this is just my assumption as your question if not well detailed.

Comment: Well I ran the SSH from the google cloud website so I don't know how to run it as the root user.

Answer (score 1):

As Alessio said, most likely you don't have permission. There are basically three approaches you could take:

1) Change the permission of the file so whatever user you are using to SSH with has permission.

2) Use sudo (or equivalent) to get access to the file, copy it someplace where the account you are using has permissions (I like to use /tmp, especially if it isn't a shared system) and then download it from there.

3) Change your login username in SSH to something that has permission. How to do this is described at the bottom of the page at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser